# Remove backslashes and quotes

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to remove double quotes and backslashes.

My code like

```
> "\"BU\"".gsub /"/, ''
=> "BU"
```

I want

```
BU
```

Please help..

Comment: What's the language? Ruby?

Comment: "\"BU\"".gsub \\", '' - not working

Comment: @YuHao - yes, it's a ruby language

Comment: there is no backslashes present in your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
a = "\"BU\""
print a.gsub('"','')
#=> BU
```

Answer (score 1):

By default irb prompt would displays the output in the format like `"string"` (ie, within double quotes). There is no backslashes present in your input, double quotes are escaped to mean a literal `"` symbol because the input string is within the delimiter double quotes while assigning it to a variable. If you do the string assignment like this `s = ""BU""`, the interpreter would treat the second `"` as the ending marker. You could probably avoid this type of issues by putting the string within single quotes (*if the input contains double quotes*), vice-versa. If both quotes are present then escaping the quotes is the only option. Use `print` function to see the actual variable contents.

```
irb(main):007:0> s = "\"BU\""
=> "\"BU\""
irb(main):008:0> print s
"BU"=> nil
irb(main):009:0> m = s.gsub(/"/, "")
=> "BU"
irb(main):010:0> print m
BU=> nil
```

.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer [String#delete](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/String.html#method-i-delete) to [String#gsub](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/String.html#method-i-gsub) here, because it takes but one argument and reads better:

```
s = "\BU\""
s.delete ?"  #=> "BU"
s            #=> "\BU\"" (s is unchanged)
s.delete! ?" #=> "BU"
s            #=> "BU"    (s is altered)
```

`s.delete ?"` is the same as `s.delete '"'` and `s.delete('"')`